# substring search

Tags: algorithm, substring

I've recently been trying to investigate the various ways to do substring searches and have stumbled upon the following article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_string_search_algorithm. I was wondering if there are any other common/efficient algorithms out there that anyone can suggest/show?

Thanks much

Comment: Did you take a look at [String searching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm)?

Comment: You already reference an article about an algorithm, that itself references other algorithms, so you appear to have already answered your own question at least partly. Are there any particular conditions or constraints you have or are you just interested in the topic in general?

Comment: i think i'm mainly looking for commonly used algorithms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious would be Boyer-Moore or some variant such as Boyer-Moore-Horspool. For some situations, it's also worth considering Knuth-Morris-Pratt.

Answer (score 0):

KMP algorithim is efficient in substring search if the text is small. 
complexity O(n).
for easy understanding 
http://jakeboxer.com/blog/2009/12/13/the-knuth-morris-pratt-algorithm-in-my-own-words/

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion by far the most intuitave and easy to understand is [Robin Karp Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm)

Here is a simple python implementation

```
def computeHash(p):
    return sum ([ value*10**index for (index,value) in enumerate(p[::-1]) ])

def getPosition(string,subString):
    kh=computeHash(subString)
    lk=len(subString)
    ans=[]
    for i in enumerate(string):
        if len(string[i[0]:i[0]+lk])<lk:
            break
        else:
            if computeHash(string[i[0]:i[0]+lk])==kh:
                ans.append((i[0],i[0]+lk))
    return ans

def main():

    s="hello world" #string
    ss="wor" #sub string

    print getPosition(map(ord,s),map(ord,ss))



if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```